# Combining 2 DC battery banks INTO A 120V 150A PANEL?

Tags: power-supply

I have 5 SLA 100A BATTERIES IN FAIRLY GOOD CONDITION.

I was hoping to be able to combine them somehow into a 120v AC power panel as my primary house power of my campervan without the need of an inverter, but use my dual fuel generator on a timer to remote start and recharge as needed.

I do have 3 small Chinese solar charge controller that also can be added to provide solar recharge capabilities but havent yet purchased panels.

HOW CAN THIS BE DONE.

Thanks for your experienced comments!

Comment: To make AC power from DC power, you need an inverter - end of story.

Answer (score 2):

OK, you're actually going to need to learn **a lot more stuff** for this project to actually happen. But this can be fun learning, hanging out on solar power, off-grid lifestyle and VanLife forums, reading and asking questions.

Remember, learning is for life. (well OK, skills can be perishable, but once you get good at learning, "learning them back" is easy.)

So here's the problem with your question on this forum.  Right now, you have skill gaps *so large* that an answer would pretty much have to be a book.  That's not allowed in this forum.

However, you're perfectly keen on buying *the expensive bits*, and you're all signed on with the idea of having large batteries.  Most people make bad choices there, and as a direct result their projects go nowhere.  So you avoided that big mistake, so your project is perfectly achievable, you just need to level up a bunch of skills.

If you don't have the patience, there are custom RV builders who will be happy to take large amounts of your money.  But I would consider it *ill-advised* to own such a specialty machine without the knowledge of how to build and repair it.

---

The idea of hooking AC power appliances directly to battery is a non-starter. Sorry, it's not gonna happen.  It's possible to run a modest RV entirely on low voltage DC but as soon as you add a refrigerator, the inverter becomes a must-have.  You're gonna learn that.  One can do small inverters, e.g. one for fridge and one per other "must have 120V" appliance.  That way you're not wasting energy keeping a large inverter spun up all the time.

As far as DC distribution panels, you can't use common AC power panels for DC **at all, period, end of subject - it's suicide. It will [catch fire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oaq2cvoPBRk) and [burn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-xInEewI_U)**.  With one single exception - Square D "QO" is rated for DC up to 48 volts.   Now they make special order breakers rated up to 120V DC, but again, if you have 120V DC on a panel you can't power AC appliances with that. Most won't work at all, and the rest will burn up their relay controls.